# docker php сервер

Tags: php, docker

я недавно начал изучать docker. Я пробовал сначала использовать его с nodejs.
А сейчас я хочу развернуть на нём php сайт.

Для этого я использую `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 index.php` и такой `Dockerfile`

```js
FROM php:7.4-cli

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8080" "index.php"]
```

Затем создаю образ и запускаю контейнер `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 myapp`
Но получаю ошибку `/bin/sh: 1: [php,: not found`

Я не пойму, из-за чего просходит эта ошибка. В index.php стандартная html разметка.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пропустили запятую в комманде:

```
CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8080" "index.php"]
```

Должно быть:

```
CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8080", "index.php"]
```